# Transaction isolation level - to which transaction is it applied?

Tags: hibernate, transactions

SHORTLY: does Isolation.READ_COMMITTED mean that the **below transaction** **can select** only commited records or does it mean that **another transaction** can read emp0 after the below transaction commits?

Let's say we have `someMethod()`, which makes `select` and `insert`. This is transaction A:

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
public Emp someMethod(Emp emp0) {
    Emp emp1 = em.find(Emp.class, 100L);// make select
    em.persist(emp0);
    return emp;
}
```

Let's say that `emp1` with the primary key 100L has been inserted by the other transaction B.

For the piece of code above (transaction A) the isolation level is set to Isolation.READ_COMMITTED. The question is for which transaction uncommited read is prohibited.

Does our annotation mean that `emp1` can be found only if the transaction B has already committed?

Or does it mean that newly persisted `emp0` can be found by one another transaction C only after our transaction A has committed?

P.S. It must be a simple question. I just can't find the answer as all the examples I've found are with the same isolation level on both sides.